# Disabling EnterpriseLibrary integration with VS2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, integration, enterprise-library

Does anyone know of a quick way to disable the Enterprise Library integration with VS. The problem is that it latches onto the AppDomain.AssemblyLoad event, and crawls through 30+ projects everytime an assembly get loaded by VS, which happens frequently if you have Workflow projects. VS becomes unusable for a few minutes everytime this happens :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting the following key helps a lot:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\Packages\{488366a4-630c-4a0e-a6a2-b019cee13bea}]
```

The freezes are less than 15 seconds now, compared to 2-4 minutes previously!  :)