# Visual Studio can't open project

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am having a problem that I have never encountered with visual studio. I can open the window to the project choosing screen, but that is about it. Next, I try and open one of my normal project folders, (that I work on daily) but it just doesn't. The editor is blank, and I can't click anything (meaning when I hover over a button and click nothing happens). In the bottom left corner, all it says is 'Initializing...'

I look up the problem and delete my `'.vs'` folder, but that does nothing. After finding nothing else, I decide to repair my installation with the installer. After that, I still couldn't open my file, so I tried to create a new project. Even this didn't work. I assume it was stuck on initializing, but it just said 'created project successfully' with the normal non-responsive window.

I decide to completely uninstall and reinstall visual studio, since I don't know what else to do. Once the installation completes, I get stuck on the same 'initializing...' as usual. I even try opening other projects that I have made and get the same initializing in the corner of the screen.

The only thing that I think could have caused this was when I pulled from github. I tried to use visual studio's built-in github interface, and had an extremely hard time getting it working. My friend and I are working on a C++ SFML game, and his reference to it is different then mine. (I know, it is dumb but I am new to c++ and don't know how all of these references work, so I let it be.) I thought visual studio's built in github thing would deal with all of the referencing on different computers, but I was wrong. I had to go back into the project properties and change all the reference locations.

Keep in mind that visual studio works completely fine for my friend, for some reason. Also, I have been using visual studio for years and had no problems opening a file. I just used C# instead of C++.

Any help would be appreciated, if I don't fix this in time I will probably be forced to switch to CodeBlocks or CLion. (I want to use VS)

Thanks a lot!

EDIT:
I tried uninstalling git for windows and restarting, but that didn't do anything. (Thanks for the suggestion)
I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling one last time, but nothing happened.
I found this page:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/94904/vs-2017-153-crashes-opening-any-new-or-existing-pr.html
It is similar to my issue, except there is no message, I just can't do anything. I followed the instructions and made a dump file, so if anyone understands it and needs it, here you go:
http://www.mediafire.com/file/6fm76bfk8782t50/devenv.DMP/file

Also, I am using my local SSD and even when I try browsing my files for the solution to open it, it does the same thing.

Comment: if you think the github software is to blame ,uninstall it ,(+ maybe a reboot) and then open your solution(s) again to see if it helped. Then reinstall github and hope it doesn't re-occur.

Comment: From time to time, I work with GIMP in my company and open image files from network drives. (This stores those file paths as recent files.) When I go home the network drives are not accessible. If I now try to load or save something, the file dialog freezes for minutes until I can choose/enter the file name. This is probably because it tries to find the recent files but it can't. Sounds somehow similar, doesn't it? (In my case, it helps very much to disconnect network drives when at home.) In short, the timeout to reach something which isn't available can make things very tedious... :-)

Comment: Regarding VS, there is also VSCode available which is similar to VS but a separate product of MS. It's Open Source. [VSCode on github](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode). Btw. IMHO the hint of engf-010 is worth a try.

Comment: Maybe lack of some privileges are the root cause. So, just try running Visual Studio as administrator.  Another thing which came to my mind is that Visual Studio's latest version (15.8) was released yesterday so this just can be a fresh bug which needs to be reported.

Comment: Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39703475/visual-studio-freezing-crashing-while-loading-solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. I tried everything. It was unfix able. I feel bad for anyone else who has this problem, I don't know what the cause is or how you fix it (easily). I tried sysinternals, and that was the last straw.

My solution: literally reinstall windows.

It works after that, but it is a bit time consuming.